# I tried to show emoji in tkinter but its shows only black and white emoji

Tags: python, tkinter, emoji

I tried to show emoji in tkinter using `emoji_data_python`, `emoji`, `emojis` libraries, but they all show black and white emoji on tkinter window. Here is my code:

```
import emoji_data_python
import emoji
import emojis
from tkinter import*
root=Tk() 
a=emoji_data_python.unified_to_char('1F603')
b=emoji.emojize(':thumbs_up:')
c=emojis.encode(':smile:')
btn=Button(root,text=a).pack()
btn2=Button(root,text=b).pack()
btn3=Button(root,text=c).pack()
mainloop()
```

Comment: did You try changing the font or any of the colors? like `bg` or `fg` or font color?